# Can't use lambda inside `std::generate`. Where did I mess up?

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, std

I got the following code which should fill a `std::vector<int>` with the binomial coefficients for a given `n` (see below).
I don't think the `binomial` function is wrong, since it does what it should do.

The error message I get is the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:62,
                 from <file>.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::generate(_FIter, _FIter, _Generator) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Generator = int]’:
<file>.cpp:38:57:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:4469:18: error: ‘__gen’ cannot be used as a function
 4469 |  *__first = __gen();
      |             ~~~~~^~
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T> v)
{
    os << "<";
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](T x) -> void { os << " " << x << " "; });
    os << ">";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int cnt{0};
    std::vector<int> v(n + 1);

    std::function<int(int, int)> binomial = [&binomial](int n, int k) -> int {
        if (k == 0 || k == n)
            return 1;
        if (k == 1)
            return n;
        return (binomial(n - 1, k - 1) + binomial(n - 1, k));
    };

    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), binomial(n, cnt++));

    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The signature of your generator function does not match the expected signature. You can use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), to resolve this issue.

Comment: you must pass something which can be called with no arguments. So it must be callable like this `lambda()`. You are passing a value.

Comment: Thank you @M.A! I didn't know about `std::bind` until now! Really helpful! :)

Comment: @MarekR Aargh, I misread the documentation then. Thank you very much!

Comment: Unrelated, but might want to add some memoization. Your solution has O(n!) complexity at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`generate` requires a callable that takes no arguments:

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&]{ return binomial(n, cnt++); });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that a generator requires no arguments!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Why should it be wrong? Isn't is just the basic recursive formular?

Comment: @paddel It should probably be `+` instead of `*` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula:~:text=Recursive%20formula%5Bedit%5D,or%20the%20trivial%20coefficients%2C%20would%20be.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Nevermind, got it! Typo.. But thank you!!

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Just saw it. Thank you! :)

Comment: @paddel Yup. Also you can remove `if (k == 1) return n;`.